Pie de pagina al imprimir
estoy intentando poner un pie de pagina al final del la ultima pagina(no que se repita en cada una), en la vista html si queda al fondo, pero en el pdf o al imprimir la vista no.
estoy generando en pdf con typescript con la librería mdToPdf que también acepta html, y el html lo genero con ejs a atreves de una plantilla donde se le agregarían datos.
estoy usando nestjs para generar la plantillas
estoy son los servicios
 generateView(template: string, data: any) {
    
    const templateContent = readFileSync(`rutaAplanillas/{template}.ejs`, 'utf-8');
    const templateEjs = render(templateContent , data).replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");//si hay saltos de linea, no se genera bien
    return templateEjs
  }

 async generatePdf(template: string, data: any): Promise<Buffer> {
        const templateEjs = this.viewService.generateView(template, data)
        const pdf = await mdToPdf({
            content: templateEjs,
        }, {

            pdf_options: {
              format:"A3",
                margin: {
                    bottom: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    top: 0  
                },

                printBackground: true,
                displayHeaderFooter: false,

            },
            stylesheet: [],
            css: ``
        })


        return pdf.content
    }

esta es la plantilla, le quite los datos, sino tendría una tabla, lo importante es que el footer siempre queda abajo
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="id=edge">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        @media print {

            .img_bottom {
                position: relative;
                color: red;
                background: green !important;
                bottom: 0;
            }
        }


        body {
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;

        }

        .img_bottom {
            position: relative;
            background: red;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div style="height:2000px">2000</div>

    <footer class="img_bottom">hola mundo</footer>

</body>



</html><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="id=edge">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        @media print {

            .img_bottom {
                position: relative;
                color: red;
                background: green !important;
                bottom: 0;
            }
        }


        body {
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;

        }

        .img_bottom {
            position: relative;
            background: red;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div style="height:2000px">2000</div>

    <footer class="img_bottom">hola mundo</footer>

</body>



</html>

en pdf queda así

en htlm queda así


Bueno sería que pusieras con que generas ese PDF, aunque parece que usas JS puro o algo así. Las preguntas con adivinación son los domingos al caer el sol.
